Cannot close encryption on a drive I format on linux
So, I have a python script and what I want it to do is to format a drive, then encrypt it and then re-format the drive. The problem I encounter is that I have to interact with the commandline and I want this to be completely automated. And also the luksClose command fails. I don't know what's wrong or what to do.
The code is specifically made for linux. The code looks like this:
def _wipe_thread(self):
        try:
            mount_point = '/mnt/myluks'
            # Attempt to unmount the device
            subprocess.run(['sudo', 'umount', self.selected_drive], check=True)

            # Perform wiping operations
            subprocess.run(['echo', 'yes', '|', 'sudo', 'mkfs.ext4', '-F', self.selected_drive], check=True)
            subprocess.run(
                ['sudo', 'cryptsetup', 'luksFormat', '--type', 'luks2', '--verify-passphrase', self.selected_drive],
                check=True)
            subprocess.run(['sudo', 'cryptsetup', 'luksClose', '--batch-mode', 'ENCRYPTED'], check=True``)
            subprocess.run(['echo', 'yes', '|', 'sudo', 'mkfs.ext4', '-F', self.selected_drive], check=True)
            subprocess.run(['sudo', 'mount', self.selected_drive, mount_point], check=True)

            # Show completion message
            messagebox.showinfo("Wipe Complete",
                                f"Drive {self.selected_drive} has been securely wiped and reformatted in ext4.")

            # Print message to terminal
            print(f"Wipe process completed for drive: {self.selected_drive}")

        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Subprocess error occurred: {e}")
        except Exception as e:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Unexpected error occurred: {str(e)}")

I tried to run it on ubuntu.
The expected output was that it would just format-encrypt-reformat without further user interaction
What happened was that I still needed human interaction with a console and an error saying that LuksClose failed.
It is different from other subprocess questions because it is about hard drive encryption and formatting. It is NOT about patterns or popens or anything in the likes

You can't run a pipeline without a shell. subprocess.run(['echo', 'yes', '|', 'sudo', 'mkfs.ext4', '-F', self.selected_drive], check=True) runs echo 'yes' '|' 'sudo' 'mkfs.ext4' '-F' etc. You want subprocess.run(['sudo', 'mkfs.ext4', '-F', self.selected_drive], input="yes\n", check=True)

Having a | in your command without shell=True is not going to work. Also sudo is problematic since it might require user input.
